# Grails Webflow not auto-reloading

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

Hey all- I'm working on some web flows for a Grails app we're building.  I'm (slowly) getting the hang of the webflows themselves, but progress is severely limited due to the fact that changes to the webflow controller are **not auto-reloading in Tomcat on save**; basically, I need to **bounce the app every time I make a change**.  As you can imagine, this is pretty painful.  I *think* auto-reload was working a couple of days ago and then stopped, but I'm not sure.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Any thoughts on how to make auto-reload work?

Thanks!

Comment: I tend to go down a path of escalation when something like this happens.  grails clean.  If that doesn't work, I nuke the %user_home%/.grails/projects/%your_project% directory.  Then I nuke the entire %user_home%/.grails/%version% directory.  This approach has solved a lot of those 'suddenly appearing' problems that show up every now and then.

Comment: Good tip- I've done that with success in oddball cases before, but after your suggestion I tried it on this issue and it didn't fix it :(

Have you worked with webflows and/or seen this before?

Thanks again.

Comment: I have done quite a bit with webflow in grails and the auto-reloading features have usually worked as expected or been correct with a grails-clean or manual clean up. If you're not doing anything tomcat-specific, you may want to try running grails uninstall-plugin tomcat, grails install-plugin jetty.  And see if you run into the same problems on Jetty.  It would at least help narrow down if it's an issue with tomcat or with your application.

Comment: Thanks again.  So I created a new project with a simple webflow and, indeed, it would update on the fly after I made changes.  So now my theory is this: the project that is having trouble was created under Grails 1.0 or 1.1.  It's been upgraded to Grails 1.3 using the Grails upgrade command.  I've noticed, though, that the Grails upgrade command leaves out a lot of things that you get with new projects- BuildConfig, specific settings, etc.  So I'm going through the project and settings with a fine-tooth comb looking for differences.  Once I've cleaned it up I'll see if it behaves differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, here's what I found:

Situation: I have a controller with a single webflow.  The first stage of the webflow uses a command object.  (Grails 1.3.1)

1)  Command and Webflow in same file; Command first:  everything works, but the controller will not auto-reload on save.

2)  Command and Webflow in same file; Webflow first:  doesn't work- a serialization exception thrown when trying to render the page that references the command object.

3)  Command and Webdlow in different files:  everything works and controller auto-reloads.

For now I'll just keep everything in separate files.  If anyone has insight into why this behavior is being exhibited, I'm all ears.